# GitHub Action Fails for Docker Registry Login

Tags: docker, shell, github, github-actions

I have a project where I'm having a shell script that pushes images into the Docker hub after a successful build. In the script, I have the following defined:

```
  echo "Attempting log in to $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL"
  echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME" --password-stdin
```

When the pipeline ran, I got to see the following message:

```
Attempting log in to hub.docker.com
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I totally do not understand why this error happens and how I should go about fixing it. I do not want to use a GitHub action job for this purpose as that would mean that my whole logic is not portable anymore to other CI systems. I want to keep this in a shell script. Any ideas on how to fix this acute problem that I have here?

Here is my GitHub actions script:

```
  - name: docker-push
    env:
      GH_REPO: github.com/${{ env.USER }}/${{ env.DEPLOYMENT_REPO_NAME }}
      API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.API_TOKEN }}
      DOCKER_APP_URL: ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}/${{ env.USER }}/plant-simulator

    run: |
      echo "Running sbt assembly for release version $RELEASE_VERSION"
      sbt "set test in assembly := {}" assembly
      bash docker/docker_push.sh && \
      bash ./.github/scripts/tag_deployment
```

Comment: I made sure that the variables are indeed getting injected.

Comment: How did you configure your Github CI? shell based executor or docker?

Comment: Could you please explain that? I have added my CI script to my post!

Comment: Where is DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD coming from?  I see an API_TOKEN secret but you haven't made any mention of DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD except trying to use it in the script.

Comment: DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD comes from secrets that I have set in the Project in my GitHub

Comment: Ok I know what you mean. Let me set if and see if that helps!

Comment: Spot on! @EdwardThomson I had to set the secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD. Thanks! Please post that as an asnwer and I will upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is running:

```sh
echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME" --password-stdin
```

Which looks correct to me.  Make sure that:

1. You have added a repository secret with the docker registry password (for consistency's sake, let's use `DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD`)

   [image]
2. You provide that secret to your script, in an environment variable.

   ```yaml
   env:
     DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets. DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
   ```